Problem with <!DOCTYPE html> in PHP with session_start() ... Apache configuration
I have faced an issue when I uploaded my source code to a hosting.
In my HTML/PHP pages, I have some code like the following one:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<?php
session_start();
....
....
?>

If I run the page in my localhost, with display_errors=On ... I do not get any error for the session, but if I run in the hosting (with same PHP version), I get this error:
Warning: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in

This error doesn't allow me to get $_SESSION variable, so I can't continue.
I'm trying to replicate in my local environment, but I can't configure the server to behave in the same way.
I have identified how to solve it (moving <!DOC....> after the session_start() command), but I would like to understand how to replicate this issue in my environment.
Is there any PHP.ini or Apache configuration that I'm missing in my local environment?
Thanks in advance.
I tried to change parameters in PHP.ini but I was not able to replicate the behaviour of the hosting environment.

session must be before any browser output, this is part of PHP documentation. Out of this - do you have valid session.save_path in your local .ini file?

Your local environment likely has output_buffering set to on (or a specific number of bytes) - which will prevent this error, because headers are only send when the first byte of the output gets send, and by buffering it, that will not have happened already at the time you call session_start.

Muchas gracias @CBroe ya soy capaz de replicarlo!!!

PHP doesn’t even know what is “”.

<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <!-- Other head elements -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your content here -->
</body>
</html>

try this code.
Note:

The session can not be started after headers have been sent. It occurs when the session_start() function is called after any output has been sent to the browser. This includes HTML, white space, or echo statements sent before calling session_start().
Ensure no spaces or lines exist before the <?php tag at the top of the file. Even a single space or line break can cause headers to be sent prematurely.
Ensure no closing PHP tags (?>) at the end of your PHP files. Leaving the PHP tag open at the end of the file can help prevent accidental whitespace or newlines from being sent to the output.

